# PHP How to add active class to dynamic menu?

Tags: php, class, dynamic, menu

how can i add active class to dynamic menu.I use while for my product list.But i cannot understand how can i add to active class.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Products</h3>
        <div class="list-group">


         <?php
         $db = new connection(); 
         $productsor = mysqli_query($db,"select * from products");

         while($productcek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productsor)){ ?>

         <a href="products.php?products_id=<?php echo $productcek['products_id'];?>" class="list-group-item"> <?php echo $productcek['products_ad']; ?> </a>
         <?php
       }
       ?>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check against a previously set _GET parameter and compare it in your while loop

```
while($productcek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productsor)){ ?>

    <?php $active = (isset($_GET['products_id']) && $productcek['products_id'] == $_GET['products_id']) ? 'active' : null; ?>

    <a href="products.php?products_id=<?php echo $productcek['products_id'];?>" class="list-group-item <?= $active; ?>"> <?php echo $productcek['products_ad']; ?> </a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: there is an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''active'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Ah I'd missed the ? in the ternary :)

Comment: thank u @Dale i have one question more.This is for my product page i come here from menu.How to give active menu without product_id because when i come this page there is no active menu and i click someone it actives.How can i do this default active class.

Comment: You would have to add a check for a !isset($_GET['products_id']) and then also make sure you only assign one link as active, but that's for another question :)

Comment: i am really begginer in php :/ i dont understand where i should add the check for a  !isset($_GET['products_id']) :(((